# How do you close the CSS preview view in Eclipse?

Tags: css, eclipse, view, window, preview

When I load up a CSS file in Eclipse, it splits the source with this annoying preview window with various elements showing how they look in the document. I cannot figure out how to remove this view, and only show the source code.

For those down voting: It clearly states in the about page that questions about "Software development tools" are allowed.

Comment: You could change which editor Eclipse uses for `.css` files.

Comment: I have to use Eclipse, I don't have a choice.

Comment: I don't mean "don't use Eclipse." I mean "change Eclipse's settings." http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-51.xhtml

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. Do you want to answer it so I can accept, or do you mind if I write the answer myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change Eclipse's settings to open `*.css` files with a different editor.

[image]

See [Eclipse help: Associating editors with file types.](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-51.xhtml)